# .aspx vs .cs class

Tags: asp.net

what is the difference between the .aspx class and the .cs class of appcode?

when i write some aspx class it's aspx.cs by default inherit the System.Web.UI.Page  and it's 
aspx paeg in page directive mention the tag inherit="page_name_what we saved with", cant we make it inherit something else like .cs class of appcode, all this confuse me please elaborate me on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `aspx` file contains your page markup. It's automatically converted into code by ASP.NET.

The `cs` file contains the [code behind](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303247) your page (initialization, event handlers, etc.). You have to write that code yourself.

**EDIT:** The `Inherits` attribute of the [@ Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx) directive associates the page markup to the code behind: when compiling the page, ASP.NET converts the markup into a class that actually inherits from the code-behind class, e.g. something like:

```
class __Generated_YourPage : YourPage
{
}
```

That's why the autowired event handlers in your code behind (e.g. `Page_Load`) have to be `protected` and not `private`.

You can change that attribute, but you have to change the name of the class in your code-behind file accordingly, or the code generated from the markup won't compile because it won't find the class it's supposed to inherit.

Comment: and what is that inherit tag in the aspx page sir, by deflaut it makes the page name by which we saved it, cant we change it..and in code behing it inherits the page. Cant it inherit some other .cs class of other page of appcode...inherit rally confuse me please elaborate me on this

Comment: in what condition we may need to inherit some other code behind for some other html page? beacause i never did this?

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet, I never did that either. I suppose it doesn't make much sense to bind markup to the code behind *another* page, especially since you can write a base `Page` class and derive all your pages from that class in most versions of ASP.NET.

Comment: ok sir, thanks a lot for your answers. In near future if i stuck somewhere i'll reopen the thread.